# AccessTokenNotAvailableException

Tags: authentication, blazor-webassembly

Getting a AccessTokenNotAvailableException error in my Blazor Web Assembly application.

This is happening when calling a webapi controller, it should be the first call to read application  data.

I am not being prompted prior to this to login, and believe this is the root problem.

I am not sure why my app is not calling the login.

I have this in app.razor:

```
<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                @if (context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated != true)
                {
                    <RedirectToLogin />
                }
                else
                {
                    <p role="alert">You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                }
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
```

and my RedirectToLogin contains this:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateToLogin("authentication/login");
    }
```

My objective is to have the user immediately directed to the login page when first reaching the application.

Not sure what else to provide.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having a problem with:

"The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted"

Set:  "TrustServerCertificate=True" in the connection string, that seems to be taking care of it.  I believe this is ok for now, in a development environment.